# FlatList and Scrollview disappear items while pull to refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

while pull to refresh the flatlist or even a scrollview i get some data from the api and if the data i get is less then the data i already displayed the whole items disappear and if it's higher it's only display the new one and if it's equal everything seems okay also if i go to other page then i return everything seems good
note : i display list of images i fetch from the api using card item from native base

```
 _getFilesOnRefresh = () => {
  axios.get(GET_ALL_FILES_URL+this.state.company_id, {
      headers: {
          'api_token':this.state.api_token
      }
  })
      .then(resp =>{
          this.state.files =  resp.data[0];
          //set the cache to the new data
          this._setCache(resp.data[0]);
          this._AppendUploadingFiles();
          if(this.state.files.data.length == 0)
          {

              this.setLoading(true);
              let message = "You Don\'t Have Any Files";
              alert_message(message);
              this._middlePageMessage(message);
          }
          else
          {

              this.setLoading(false);
              // this.state.files.data = this.state.files.data.reverse();
              success_message("Displayed "+this.state.files.data.length+" Files");
          }
          // stop refreshing
          this.setRefresh(false);
      })
      .catch(function(error){
          console.log('on refresh error',error);
          // console.log(error)
          let message = 'Check Your Connection!';
          // this.setLoading(true);
          alert_message(message);
          // this._middlePageMessage(message);
          // stop refreshing
          this.setRefresh(false);
      }.bind(this)); };
_handleRefresh = () => {
    if(!_getUploadingFlag()){// if he's uploading don't do anything else refresh
        this.setRefresh(true);
        this._getFilesOnRefresh();
    }
};

render() {
if(this.state.isLoading){
  return(
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <MenuHeader title="My Requests" obj={this.props}/>
          {this.state.LoadingOutput}
            <FabAddFiles currentPage={this}/>
      </Container>
  );
}
else{

  for (let index = 0; index < this.state.files.data.length; index++) {
    if(this.state.files.data[index].file_status == 'pending' || this.state.files.data[index].file_status == 'in-progress')
      this.state.files.data[index].type = fileStatus['pending'];
    else if(this.state.files.data[index].type == 'Sales'){
      this.state.files.data[index].type = <Icon ACTIVE name="document" style={{color:colors.success_color,fontSize:45}}/>;
    }else if(this.state.files.data[index].type == 'Purchase'){
      this.state.files.data[index].type = <Icon type="FontAwesome" name="shopping-cart" style={{color:colors.danger_color,fontSize:40}}/>;
    }
    if(this.state.files.data[index].images.length == 0){
      //create image path if it's not exist
      let imagePath = {image_path:'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRvcJY57vM025nSOBjfKbo6pC0pMIMMHEdDcJZprWFigxXCIqhRVA'};
      this.state.files.data[index].images.push(imagePath);
    }
  }
  // create list
  let files_elemnts = this.state.files.data.map(item => {
      return(
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ShowFile' , {item:item})}>
              <Content  style={styles.File_box} >
                  <Card style={styles.card} >
                      <CardItem style={styles.card_item}>
                          <Left style={{flex:1,borderRadius:15}}>
                              <Image
                                  // resizeMethod={'resize'}
                                  source={{uri: item.images[0].image_path}}
                                  indicator={ProgressPie}
                                  // renderError={console.log('error')}
                                  indicatorProps={{
                                      size: 80,
                                      color: colors.secondary_color,
                                      unfilledColor: colors.third_color
                                  }}
                                  style={{
                                      width: 100,
                                      height: 120,
                                  }}
                                  borderRadius={10}
                              />
                          </Left>

                          <Body style={{flex:1.4}}>
                          <Text style={styles.file_status}>{item.description.length > 0 ? item.description : headerStatus[item.file_status]}</Text>
                          <Text note style={styles.date}>
                              <Icon active name="calendar" style={styles.icon}/> {item.date}
                          </Text>
                          <Text note style={styles.time}><Icon active name="time" style={styles.icon}/> {item.time}</Text>
                          {item.amount !=0 ? <Text style={styles.money}>AED {item.amount}</Text> :null}
                          </Body>

                          <Right style={{flex:0.4}}>
                              {item.type}
                              <Text style={styles.mainIcon}></Text>
                              {item.file_status == 'in-progress' || item.file_status == 'pending'  ? null :fileStatus[item.file_status] }
                          </Right>

                      </CardItem>
                  </Card>
              </Content>
          </TouchableHighlight>
      )
  });


return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
      <MenuHeader title="My Requests" obj={this.props}/>
      {/*<View style={{flex:0.1}}>*/}
      {/*/!*<Text style={styles.headeing}>{this.state.company_name}</Text>*!/*/}
      {/*</View>*/}
          <ScrollView refreshControl={
              <RefreshControl
                  refreshing={this.state.refresh}
                  onRefresh={this._handleRefresh}
              />
          }>
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
            {files_elemnts}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
        <FabAddFiles currentPage={this}/>
      </Container>); }
```

in case i use flatlist

```
<FlatList
                    style={{marginBottom:20}}
                    onRefresh={this._handleRefresh}
                    refreshing={this.state.refresh}
                    initialNumToRender={30}
                    extraData={this.state.reRender}
                    data={this.state.files.data}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    renderItem={({item}) =>
                        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ShowFile' , {item:item})}>
                            <Content  style={styles.File_box} >
                                <Card style={styles.card} >
                                    <CardItem style={styles.card_item}>
                                        <Left style={{flex:1,borderRadius:15}}>
                                            <Image
                                                // resizeMethod={'resize'}
                                                source={{uri: item.images[0].image_path}}
                                                indicator={ProgressPie}
                                                // renderError={console.log('error')}
                                                indicatorProps={{
                                                    size: 80,
                                                    color: colors.secondary_color,
                                                    unfilledColor: colors.third_color
                                                }}
                                                style={{
                                                    width: 100,
                                                    height: 120,
                                                }}
                                                borderRadius={10}
                                            />
                                        </Left>

                                        <Body style={{flex:1.4}}>
                                        <Text style={styles.file_status}>{item.description.length > 0 ? item.description : headerStatus[item.file_status]}</Text>
                                        <Text note style={styles.date}>
                                            <Icon active name="calendar" style={styles.icon}/> {item.date}
                                        </Text>
                                        <Text note style={styles.time}><Icon active name="time" style={styles.icon}/> {item.time}</Text>
                                        {item.amount !==0 ? <Text style={styles.money}>AED {item.amount}</Text> :null}
                                        </Body>

                                        <Right style={{flex:0.4}}>
                                            {item.type}
                                            <Text style={styles.mainIcon}></Text>
                                            {item.file_status == 'in-progress' || item.file_status == 'pending'  ? null :fileStatus[item.file_status] }
                                        </Right>

                                    </CardItem>
                                </Card>
                            </Content>
                        </TouchableHighlight>}
                />
```

Comment: 1) You rewriting the files every time.

Comment: 2) Use `this.setState()` for setting data to the `state`. `this.state.file = ...` is not a good idea

Comment: yes it's solved my problem but why ?? the only reason i do this.state.files is i don't want to reRender the list until i set the cache

Comment: okay it's solved the problem if i used scrollview but if i used flatlist the problem still proceed